Bind9 in a container and host with cloudflared. Why external resolution is unencrypted?
a few days ago I was doing some experiments with bind9 on docker and I encountered some anomalous behavior
While waiting for bind to update to stable 9.20 with support for DOH also on upstream servers, I have always used this guide in my DNS servers:
Cloudflared Guide
I always got this result when I checked 1.1.1.1/help
DOHOK
However, if I run docker bind9 on a host running cloudflared I get this result
DOHKO
My named.conf:
tls local-tls {
   key-file "/etc/bind/ssl/privkey.pem";
   cert-file "/etc/bind/ssl/fullchain.pem";
};

options {
        listen-on port 53 {any;};
        listen-on port 443 tls local-tls http default {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
        recursion yes;
        forwarders {
                127.0.0.1 port 5053;
        };
};

Also tried to use:
tls local-tls {
   key-file "/etc/bind/ssl/privkey.pem";
   cert-file "/etc/bind/ssl/fullchain.pem";
};

options {
        listen-on port 53 {any;};
        listen-on port 443 tls local-tls http default {any;};
        allow-query {any;};
        recursion yes;
        forwarders {
                172.17.0.1 port 5053;
        };
};

But the outcome is the same
My docker compose file:
version: '3'

services:
  bind9:
    image: ubuntu/bind9
    container_name: bind9
    environment:
      - BIND9_USER=root
      - TZ=Europe/Rome
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "443:443/tcp"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/bind
      - ./cache:/var/cache/bind
      - ./records:/var/lib/bind
      - ./ssl:/etc/bind/ssl
      - ./zones:/etc/bind/zones
      - ./keys:/etc/bind/keys
      - ./run:/var/run
    restart: unless-stopped

Sameone can point me in the right direction?
Thanks :)
Enable DOH in upstream server in a dockerized BIND9 enviroment

I have find a solution
In this file
/etc/default/cloudflared
Add the option -address 0.0.0.0
This way:
CLOUDFLARED_OPTS=-address 0.0.0.0 --port 5053 --upstream https://1.1.1.1/dns-query --upstream https://1.0.0.1/dns-query
Then go to the named.conf file and add the docker host address ad forwarder, generally is 172.17.0.1
    forwarders {
            172.17.0.1 port 5053;
    };

Now it works!!!
For better security you can also use the 172.17.0.1 address in the -address option.
In this way the dns proxy only accept connections from the docker network.
CLOUDFLARED_OPTS=-address 172.17.0.1 --port 5053 --upstream https://1.1.1.1/dns-query --upstream https://1.0.0.1/dns-query
